# How to know the user context on a trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I want a trigger on the metadata table of CRM that fire when people delete fields.

This is working fine, but I don't know how to get the user who sent the request to delete the field.

There's any way to know this?

This is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trg_InsertMetadataAttributeDELETE
   ON  metadataschema.Attribute
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO MIGRACIONDATOS.TablaLogAtributos (Fecha, Entidad, Atributo)
    SELECT Getdate(), E.Name, A.Name
       FROM Deleted A
            INNER JOIN metadataschema.Entity E 
                ON A.EntityID = E.EntityID

END
GO
```

**The CRM organization is not upgraded to UR12 and it cannot be upgraded**

**UPDATE: It is not posible if the roll up if inferior to 12.**

Comment: Wouldn't it be the CRMAPP user you see here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulating the CRM database in any way other than tweaking indexes is unsupported by Microsoft.
Assuming you have UR12 installed (if not, I highly suggest you do it ASAP) the `Microsoft.Xrm.Metadata.Query` provides a supported tool.

[Retrieve and Detect Changes to Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863599(v=crm.5).aspx)

> The classes in the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata.Query namespace and the RetrieveMetadataChangesRequest and RetrieveMetadataChangesResponse classes let you build efficient metadata queries and capture changes to metadata as they occur over time.
>
> *[Code samples are provided in the linked MSDN section]*

Comment: Sorry, I don't have UR12 and we can't upgrade yet. UR12 provides powerfull tools but it's not an option at this moment.

Comment: Edited the question to include that *vital* information. I'll leave the answer here in case someone with UR12 comes by with a similar need.

Comment: This is the correct answer and it is not posible if the roll up is inferior to 12. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
See if these help you :  All executable in triggers.

-- get the user name
SELECT SUSER_SNAME();

-- get the event data. Which you can parse and retrieve the event command, scheme, objects....
DECLARE @EventData XML;
    SET @EventData  = EVENTDATA();
-- Then parse the xml. For example :
SELECT @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]',   'NVARCHAR(100)'), 
SELECT @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),

-- Get connection specific data 
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
    WHERE session_id = @@SPID;

-- Get session specific data on whomever executed the process that fired the trigger
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
    WHERE session_id = @@SPID;
```

see link for the usage of EVENTDATA() : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173781.aspx

Comment: Hello, the EventData() return null, I think is becasue it is a DML proccess and not a DDL.

Comment: Selecting the SUSER_NAME(), or from sys.dm_exec_sessions will work.

Comment: I think you can't know this on a trigger, at least the information I need, thank you anyway